# Strip undesired values from Rails' time_select()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Can anybody point me to a solution for stripping out undesired values from a Ruby on Rails `time_select`?

Basically, `time_select` shows all hours from `00` to `24`, but in my app I need to prevent users from choosing hours before 08 and after 16 directly in the `SELECT` tag and there does not seem to be a corresponding option I can pass to `time_select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [select_time](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_time) or [select_hour](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour).

```
select_time(my_time, start_hour: 8, end_hour: 16) # Generates a time select field with hours that range from 8 to 16

select_hour(my_time, start_hour: 8, end_hour: 16) # Generates a time select field with hours that range from 8 to 16
```

So that restricting the user to select time in between 8 and 16.

Answer (score 0):

```
select_time(my_time, start_hour: 8, end_hour: 16)
```